# Performing operations between couples of partitions in Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, partition

I am new to Java and Spark, so bear with me if any part of the question sounds blasphemous.

I am writing a Java application using Spark on my local machine. I have created a JavaPairRDD that I have partitioned according to a custom partioner I have written. Each entry carries a partition ID key and a Tuple2 value.

I would like to perform operations between DISJOINT pairs of partitions. That is, if I have "d" partitions, I would have C(d,2) unique combinations of partitions, and perform operations between the elements of those combinations of partitions.

I would glady avoid repetitions (e.g. performing an operation with the elements of partition 1 and 5 and then between the elements of 5 and 1).

What is the best way around doing this?

Comment: Any reason you need JavaPairRDD and not dataframes (Dataset<Row>)?

Comment: My knowledge of dataframes is not enough to say why I am not using them!

Comment: Might be worse considering... it's a fast learning process and might be easier for you to get to your end result.

Comment: Do you suggest to look at any method in particular?

Comment: You could look at https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.labs.spark, specifically the l200 series of labs.